# How to set up routes correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, path, routes

I can untrash all the messages checked in index view without any problem.
But in show view, the link generated show the link to /messages/discard.3
this 3 could be ID.

How can I make it work? it should be linked to messages/discard/3

My files are like these

routes.rb

```
  get "messages/received"
  get "messages/sent"
  get "messages/trash"
  get 'messages/:id' => 'messages#show', :as => :show_messages

  match 'messages/new/:username', :to => 'messages#new', :as => :new_messages
  match 'messages/deliver' => 'messages#deliver', :via => :post
  match 'messages/discard' => 'messages#discard', :via => :post, :as => :discard_messages
  match 'messages/untrash' => 'messages#untrash', :via => :post
```

view 1 (index.html.erb)

```
  <%= form_tag(:action=> discard) do %>   
   <% @messages.each do |m| %>
      <tr>
       <td><%= check_box_tag "checked_items[#{m.id}]",m.id %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_message.id %></td>
       <td><%= 'unread' if m.is_unread?(current_user) %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_message.created_at %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_sender.username %></td>
       <td><%= link_to m.subject, show_messages_path(m) %></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
```

view 2 (show.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to 'Trash', discard_messages_path(@messages)  %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
  def discard
      conversation = Conversation.find_all_by_id(params[:checked_items].keys)
    if conversation
      current_user.trash(conversation)
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent to trash."
    else
      conversations = Conversation.find(params[:conversations])
      conversations.each { |c| current_user.trash(c) }
      flash[:notice] = "Messages sent to trash."
    end
       redirect_to :back 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try change it to:

```
match 'messages/discard/:id' => 'messages#discard', :via => :post, :as => :discard_messages
```

However I think what you *should* do is to change your all routes to:

```
resource :messages do
  member do
    #code
  end

  collection do
    #code
  end
end
```

It's easier to read and maintain

Comment: Thanks!! I changed it to your first suggestion. but it says Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"discard", :controller=>"messages"} :(